# Sequence Autoencoder for compression

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I'm want to build a sequence to sequence auto encoder for signal compression.
I wanted to start with a std, LSTM based auto encoder. However, Keras complains about my model. any hint what I'm doing wrong

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model


timesteps = 10
input_dim = 4

latent_dim = 128

#Create the encoder:
inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)

#Create the decoder:
decInput = Input(shape=(latent_dim))    
decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(decInput)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)
decoder = Model(decInput,decoded)

#Joining models:
joinedInput = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoderOut = encoder(joinedInput)    
joinedOut = decoder(encoderOut)
sequence_autoencoder = Model(joinedInput,joinedOut)
```

I get on the line `encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)`

The error

> TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.

Comment: Try `decInput = Input(shape=(latent_dim,)) `

Comment: Gives a new error message `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_18: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`

Comment: The code works with Marcin correction on my end. What are your keras and backend version?

Comment: da** it ;-) installed tensor flow not in the iphython kernel: `print(tf.__version__) = 0.12.0` `print(keras.__version__) = 2.0.5`